# Crawling twitter,linkedin using nutch

Tags: linkedin-api, nutch, web-crawler

I have been trying to use nutch to crawl twitter and linkedin data
Nutch-0.9.

1. However when i try to crawl twitter the regex-filter doesnt seem to work, my regex-filter file has 
   +^https://([a-z0-9]*.)*twitter.com/a*
   and what i wish to do is to crawl only those urls that follow the above pattern. I end up with urls such as https://twitter.com/document.
2. As for the linkedin part, it always shows a timeout whenever i try to crawl it, robots.txt on linkedin says that you need to mail to get your crawler whitelisted but they never respond.

Appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0):

f you want to crawl this specific urls you should include following line too

> -.*

this command will exclude all other urls!
Also if you want to crawl twitter or linkedin, you can use specified crawlers like [twit4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/) or [linkedin-j](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/)!

Answer (score 0):

As I know so far, Nutch did not support crawling Twitter and Linkedin data. For crawling Titter data you should using Twitter API, check this one http://twitter4j.org/en/. For crawling Linked data, you could have a look on this https://github.com/pondering/scrapy-linkedin.

Hope this helps